# How to safely deserialize keys/data format JSON response

Tags: c#, arrays, json, web-services, json.net

I am getting this 'optimized' JSON response from a third party web service presented as follows, I built the type as per the information presented in the keys but the difficulty I am facing is that data is not represented in objects but in arrays, is there a way to automate the building and value mapping of my objects list?

```
{
    "reports": {
        "query": {
            "keys": [{
                "name": "Date",
                "type": "date"
            }, {
                "name": "NetSales",
                "type": "price"
            }, {
                "name": "GrossCash",
                "type": "price"
            }, {
                "name": "GrossCard",
                "type": "price"
            }, {
                "name": "GrossDelivery",
                "type": "price"
            }, {
                "name": "NetFood",
                "type": "price"
            }, {
                "name": "NetDrink",
                "type": "price"
            }, {
                "name": "NetRetail",
                "type": "price"
            }, {
                "name": "Baskets",
                "type": "int"
            }],
            "data": [
                [1523577600000, 51924, 11300, 27200, 9900, null, null, null, 8],
                [1523404800000, 7434, 2600, 3900, null, null, null, null, 6],
                [1523491200000, 18101, 4000, 10100, null, null, null, null, 5],
                [1523664000000, 13243, 7400, 6500, null, null, null, null, 3],
                [1523750400000, 11718, 7300, null, 5000, null, null, null, 2],
                [1523836800000, 16576, 7700, 4800, 4900, null, null, null, 4],
                [1524096000000, 20293, 9100, 6000, null, null, null, null, 4]
            ]
        }
    },
    "api": {
        "message": {
            "success": {
                "202": {
                    "id": 202,
                    "title": "Token is valid",
                    "details": "Token is validated and found valid."
                }
            }
        },
        "codeBaseVersion": 1,
        "executionTime_milliSeconds": 43
    }
}
```

I ended up with this code but not satisfied with it:

```
JObject myOpject = JObject.Parse(responseString);

List<JToken> setOfObjects = myOpject["reports"]["query"]["data"].Children().ToList();
var listOfData = new List<Data2>();
foreach (var token in setOfObjects)
{
    var myObject = new Data2
    {
        NetSales = decimal.Parse(token[1].ToString()),
        //etc.

    };

    listOfData.Add(myObject);
}
```

Comment: how dynamic are the keys? there are two camps here. create a custom DynamicObject that can interpret the data or create a strongly typed model that would match the keys and then use reflection to match the properties to the keys and build you objects.

Comment: @Nkosi they are stable, but I need as you said a mapping to a strongly typed model and map to it. could you provide a sample code that illustrates what you said?

Comment: Here is a thought, using the same JToken idea transform the data using the keys to create a object model and then deserialize that to the strong type desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the same JToken idea transform the data using the keys to create a new object model and then deserialize that to the strong type desired.

For example, taking a few records you can transform the keys and data to

```
[
  {
    "Date": 1523577600000,
    "NetSales": 51924,
    ...
  },
  {
    "Date": 1523404800000,
    "NetSales": 7434,
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

The following code attempts to build that using the key index matched to the index of item in data array

```
JObject myOpject = JObject.Parse(responseString);
List<JToken> keys = myOpject["reports"]["query"]["keys"].Children().ToList();
List<JToken> data = myOpject["reports"]["query"]["data"].Children().ToList();

var array = new JArray();
foreach (var token in data) {
    var record = new JObject();
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++) {
        var propertyName = keys[i]["name"].Value<string>();
        var propertyValue = token[i];
        record[propertyName] = propertyValue;                    
    }
    array.Add(record);                
}

var listOfData = array.ToObject<List<Data2>>(); // or Data2[], etc
```

assuming `Data2` is your strongly typed model with matching properties.

Comment: Gotcha..basically you are transforming it to the familiar JSON, then converting

Comment: @HichemSeeSharp yes, that is the idea.

Comment: do you have an idea how to convert the integer provided to Datetime? I ignore what standard it comes from. using Ticks gives me wrong date.

Comment: @HichemSeeSharp what standard did it come from? is it a unix date?

Comment: @HichemSeeSharp I tested it with `1523577600000` and got `4/13/2018 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: What conversion you used?

Comment: @HichemSeeSharp check out this example of how I converted it https://dotnetfiddle.net/HQ1InQ

Comment: Thanks for the prompt assistance @Nkosi